# How to manage HATEOAS links when the server is the client?

Tags: rest, hateoas

I'm learning about HATEOAS. The backend server I'm working on will use a third party REST API that uses HATEOAS. That API has an end point to return the url for each resource and also returns the related resource links with regular requests.

But I'm wondering what's a good way to manage these links on the server to avoid hardcoding them. For example if the third party changes the url of the resource, how will the server detect that change? Are there any standard practices for managing HATEOAS resource links?

Possible ways I can think of

1. When the server starts, get all the resources urls and cache them. Whenever the third party API needs to be called, reuse these cached urls. Whenever there is a 404 or related error, update the resource url. Or update the url periodically in intervals.
2. Get the resource url each time before calling the end point. Simplest but essentially doubles the number of requests.

But neither sound like robust ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While discovery is generally a good thing and should allow a HATEOAS system to introduce changes in ways that 'hardcoded urls' don't, if urls start breaking arbitrarily I would still consider this a major issue.

You should be able to store urls / links on your side and have some expectation that those keep working.

There are some mechanisms that deal with changes though:

1. The server should return `301` / `308` redirects if a resource moved. If this were the case, you should also update your references.
2. The server can emit `Sunset` or `Deprecated` headers. See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8594

Those are more general answers, but ultimately the existence of best practices does not mean that vendors will abide by them. With that in mind I think your best bet is to try and find out what the deprecation policy is of your vendor and see what *they* recommend.

Answer (score 1):

3. Use a cached resource if it is valid, request a refresh when you don't have a local valid copy.

[RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) defines the caching semantics of HTTP.

Ideally, you don't implement the caching rules yourself, but instead you use a general purpose cache.

In its ideal form, your bespoke implementation is talking to a headless browser, and the headless browser worries about the caching rules for you.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you need the initial URL to start the process, and everything else comes from that.

Each resource you get from the server should include links to other edges on the graph of service for that resource.

So, once you get the initial resource, all of the rest come automatically.

That said, it's not untoward to have "well known" entry points that are, ideally, unchanging URLs. But in the end, those are just "bookmarks", and not necessarily guaranteed end points.

Consider a shopping site such as Amazon. Outside of `amazon.com`, you don't know any of their URLs. They're all provided on the various forms and pages, and the human simply navigates the site. Those URLs can be changing all the time, and no one would know. With HATEOAS, it's up to the machine to follow the links, rather than a human. But the process of navigation is the same.

As others have mentioned, idea of caching a root resource has merit. Then you rely on the caching headers to direct you to how often you have to refresh the links.

But that said, operationally, there's no difference between following a normal link, and following a cached link. Underneath, the cached resource loads faster, but you still need to "follow the link". Because that's where the caching behavior kicks in. This is different from assuming the link is good, assuming you know the result of a resource lookup. Your application follows the link. Always. The underlying infrastructure is responsible for making it efficient.

So, your code should not, say, load up a root resource, and then stuff a map filled with links, and then assume they're good. Rather, the code should request the root resource, perhaps as a Map of links (datatypes for the win), and let the next layer handle the details. Because it all depends on the type of caching involved. Some have coded durations where no followup is necessary. Others, you make the request anyway, and the server tier responds back "nothing changed", so you can use your local copy, but you're still require to ask in the first place.

Those are implementation details that the SERVER mandates (not the client). It's a server contract. If they want you pinging them each and every time, so be it. That's the contract they're presenting to you and if you want to be a Good Citizen, then you should honor that contact.

Ideally, the server makes good decisions on these kinds of issues for the sake of efficiency, but in the end it's really up to them.

The client has to go along. The client in a HATEOAS system cedes a lot to the server. They're simply not decisions for the client to make.